# (Matlab) Dimensional indexing using indices returned by min function

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, minimum

Suppose I have a 5-d matrix C. I use the following code to get a min matrix C3 (each element of C3 represents the minimum of dimension 1,2,3):

```
[C1, I1] = min(C,[],1);
[C2, I2] = min(C1, [], 2);
[C3, I3] = min(C2, [], 3);
```

The question is how to get the index of the minimum in terms of each dimension? For example consider this simpler case:

```
C = [1,2;3,4]
```

The minimum here is 1, its index in dimension 1 is 1 (first row) and in dimension 2 also 1 (first column).

I know that changing the sequence of these expressions would give me the right answer, but what if I want to get all dimensional indices with computing these expressions only once?

Comment: the first min, (depending on the size of the input matrix), returns a vector of indices, not a number. And this is not a whole row or column. This vector is the minimum numbers in each row, collected into one vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for a 5D matrix -

```
[~,ind] = min(C(:))
[ind_dim1,ind_dim2,ind_dim3,ind_dim4,ind_dim5] = ind2sub(size(C),ind)
```

**Edit 1:** This is for a case where you are not exactly looking for global but dimension specific minimum values and indices.

**Code**

```
%%// Random data for demo
C = randi(60,2,3,4,2,3);

%%// Your method
[C1, I1] = min(C,[],1)
[C2, I2] = min(C1, [], 2)
[C3, I3] = min(C2, [], 3)

%%// My method
dimID = 3; %%// Dimension till when minimum is to be found out
C_size = size(C);
dim_v1 = prod(C_size(1:dimID))
dim_v2 = prod(C_size(1:dimID-1))

t1 = reshape(C,[dim_v1 C_size(dimID+1:end)])
[val,ind1] = min(t1,[],1)
chk1_ind = ceil(ind1/dim_v2)

%%// This might suffice for you, but you insist to get the indices in the format 
%%// identical to the one obtained from your method, try the next steps

C_size(1:dimID)=1;
chk2_ind = reshape(chk1_ind,C_size)

%%// Verify
error_check = isequal(chk2_ind,I3)
```

Comment: So I am not computing the global minimum, rather, I only want minimum of some dimensions. Is there any convenient way to do that?

Comment: @user3577923 Just to make it clear to us maybe take some sample input values and show us the desired output? Some sample 3D or maybe 4D input?

Comment: @user3577923 Check out **Edit 1**!  Notice we are only using `min` once. `chk1_ind` or `chk2_ind` is what you are after I am guessing.